# Fazendo cálculo de saldo e separação por moeda

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou precisando de ajuda para fazer uma função a qual eu consigo saber o saldo de faturas dos clientes e que o valor fique separado por moedas das faturas (Por exemplo  250 USD | 340 EUR) pois existem faturas com moedas diferentes. Além disso existem requisitos a serem cumpridos para as faturas entrarem na conta de saldo.

Vou deixar uma print da tabela e mostrar um select que eu já havia feito  que contempla outros campos que irei utilizar também para montar uma lista dinâmica que estou fazendo.

A ideia da lista é mostrar Cliente por cliente, sem repetição, com todas as faturas competindo aos requisitos e seu saldo de acordo com as moedas que existem nas faturas e gostaria de ajuda para fazer isso pois não sei como posso fazer esse calculo.

```
        SELECT * FROM (
    Select      -- Campos fatura
         FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
        ,FATU.ID_CD_BOOKING
        ,FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA --> indica que o valor vai ser a ser somado para obter o saldo
        ,FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE --> indica que o valor vai ser subtraído para obter o saldo
        ,FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO
        ,FATU.ID_CD_LOGIN
        ,FATU.IN_STATUS
        ,FATU.DH_CADASTRO
        ,FATU.DH_VENCIMENTO
        ,FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_REL

        ,NM_PAGREC              = (Select
                                        CASE WHEN CRMP.IN_TIPO = 'F' THEN
                                            CRMP.NM_PESSOA+' '+CRMP.NM_SOBRENOME +'<br>'+convert(varchar,CRMP.NR_CPF_CNPJ)
                                        ELSE
                                            CRMP.NM_APELIDO  +'<br>'+convert(varchar,CRMP.NR_CPF_CNPJ)
                                        END
                                    From 
                                        TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP     CRMP
                                    Where 
                                        ID_CD_PESSOA            = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA OR ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
                                    )
        ,ID_CD_PESSOA   = (Select
                                        CASE WHEN CRMP.IN_TIPO = 'F' THEN
                                            CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA
                                        ELSE
                                            CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA
                                        END
                                    From 
                                        TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP     CRMP
                                    Where 
                                        ID_CD_PESSOA            = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA OR ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
                                    ) -- Campo do ID do Cliente a ser utilizado para listar
        -- TIPO DE FATURA
        ,FATU.FL_CONV_MOEDA_BRL 
        ,FATP.DS_TITULO         AS DS_FATURA_TIPO
        ,FATP.DS_TITULO_EN      AS DS_FATURA_TIPO_EN

        -- BOOKING
        ,BOOK.FL_IMPOEXPO
        ,BOOK.DS_BOOK_NUMERO
        ,BOOK.DS_AMS_REFERENCE
        ,NM_AGENCIA_AUX             = (Select Case When IN_TIPO = 'J' Then NM_APELIDO Else NM_PESSOA + ' ' + NM_SOBRENOME End From TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP CRMP6 Where CRMP6.ID_CD_PESSOA = BOOK.ID_CD_AGENCIA_AUX)
        ,NM_ARMADOR_AUX             = (Select Case When IN_TIPO = 'J' Then NM_APELIDO Else NM_PESSOA + ' ' + NM_SOBRENOME End From TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP CRMP7 Where CRMP7.ID_CD_PESSOA = BOOK.ID_CD_ARMADOR_AUX)

        -- ADICIONAIS
        ,TEM_FECHAMENTO.FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO
        ,TEM_FECHAMENTO.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI

        -- FINANCEIRO
        ,TEM_LANCAMENTO.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
        ,TEM_LANCAMENTO.FL_COMPENSADO 
        ,TEM_LANCAMENTO.DT_ULTIMO_PAGTO

        ,COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL,0)        AS VL_FATURA_TOTAL
        ,COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA,0)  AS VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA -> Valor para o calculo
        ,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL  = (SELECT TOP(1) CASE WHEN FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA IS NOT NULL THEN FAIT.DS_MOEDA_VENDA ELSE FAIT.DS_MOEDA_CUSTO END DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL FROM TB_FATURA_ITENS_FAIT FAIT WHERE FAIT.ID_CD_FATURA = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA)
    From 
        TB_FATURA_FATU              FATU INNER JOIN
        TB_BOOKING_BOOK             BOOK ON BOOK.ID_CD_BOOKING      = FATU.ID_CD_BOOKING        INNER JOIN
        TB_FATURAS_TIPOS_FATP       FATP ON FATP.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO  = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO    INNER JOIN
        TB_LOGIN_LOGI               LOGI ON LOGI.ID_CD_LOGIN        = FATU.ID_CD_LOGIN
        OUTER APPLY (
            Select top 1 
                FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO = 'S'
                ,FAPR2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI 
            From 
                TB_FATURA_AUX_FPAX FPAX2 INNER JOIN 
                TB_FATURA_PRINCIPAL_FAPR FAPR2 ON FAPR2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI = FPAX2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI  
            Where 
                FPAX2.ID_CD_FATURA = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA AND FAPR2.IN_STATUS = 1
        ) AS TEM_FECHAMENTO

        OUTER APPLY (    
                        SELECT TOP 1 
                            ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  
                            ,FL_COMPENSADO = ( SELECT TOP 1 
                                                    'N'
                                                FROM 
                                                    TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP2 
                                                WHERE 
                                                    FNLP2.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  = FNLP.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
                                                AND FNLP2.ID_CD_AUXILIAR    = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                                                AND FNLP2.FL_AUXILIAR       = 'FAT'  
                                                AND FNLP2.FL_SITUACAO       = 'A')
                            ,DT_ULTIMO_PAGTO = ( SELECT TOP 1 
                                                    FNLP3.DT_COMPENSADO
                                                FROM 
                                                    TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP3 
                                                WHERE 
                                                    FNLP3.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  = FNLP.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
                                                AND FNLP3.ID_CD_AUXILIAR    = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                                                AND FNLP3.FL_AUXILIAR       = 'FAT'  
                                                AND (FNLP3.FL_SITUACAO      = 'C' OR FNLP3.FL_SITUACAO      = 'G')
                                                ORDER BY ID_CD_PARCELA DESC)
                        FROM 
                            TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP 
                        WHERE 
                            FNLP.ID_CD_AUXILIAR = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                        AND FNLP.FL_AUXILIAR    = 'FAT'  
                        AND FNLP.FL_CANCELADO   = 'N'
                    ) AS TEM_LANCAMENTO
                        WHERE ID_CD_FATURA <> '' ) TB       
                        WHERE ((ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO = '3' AND IN_STATUS = '1') AND (ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA = @ID_CD_PESSOA OR ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE = @ID_CD_PESSOA) AND ((FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO = '' OR FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO = NULL) AND (ID_CD_LANCAMENTO = '' OR ID_CD_LANCAMENTO = NULL)) -- Aqui tem os requisitos das faturas que devem cair na regra para ter um saldo do cliente.
```

Se tiver algo mal explicado por favor me falem que tento esclarecer a dúvida.

Desde já obrigado pela ajuda.

[image: Campos da tabela]

Resultado que espero ter é este abaixo

[image: RESULTADO ESPERADO]

Comment: O ideal seria que você colocasse a estrutura dos dados (`CREATE TABLE`) com alguns dados disponíveis (`INSERT INTO`)  e um exemplo do que você esperaria com os dados de exemplo, assim podemos testar diversas possibilidades e apresentá-las a você com os dados já validados

Comment: Por acaso o valor da fatura está expresso na moeda indicada em DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL ou está expresso em alguma outra moeda padrão? Quais são as outras moedas que existem nas faturas já que, me parece, existir apenas um campo indicando a moeda?

Comment: Acho que entendi, é que como uso outras funções dentro de uma procedure para completar essa listagem, ficaria muito grande para postar aqui, mas vou atualizar com um Select e o que eu espero de resultado.

Comment: @anonimo o valor da fatura está em VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA e o tipo da moeda da fatura é o DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL. Cada fatura tem um valor e uma moeda, o ponto é que o que eu preciso é uma espécie de agrupamento das faturas para que exista um saldo para cada moeda se existir mais que uma. Por exemplo, posso ter 6 faturas em USD e uma em EUR, logicamente os valores são diferentes por isso precisava deles separados.

Comment: Neste caso não bastaria um GROUP BY cliente, moeda com a função de agregação SUM sobre o valor da fatura?

Comment: Como consigo fazer o Group BY e o SUM sem perder os requisitos que as faturas tem de cumprir?

Comment: A `query` que você apresentou é muito complexa e, sem dados de exemplo para utilizarmos é complicado sugerir uma resposta. O ideal é que você demonstre seu problema usando algum Fiddle como o [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) ou o [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Não estou conseguindo usar os Fiddle, pois são diversas tabelas com FK. porém fiz upload de um excel com o resultado do meu script. https://www.dropbox.com/s/msm04wae6g595vu/Pasta1.xlsx?dl=0    A ideia é que eu possa ter um saldo do VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA, de cada cliente, lembrando que temos o ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA (+) E ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE (-) E A SUA DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL, por exemplo se existe uma fatura em USD e outra em BRL duas linhas do mesmo cliente com o saldo referente as moedas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom galera, consegui resolver a situação que eu tinha com alguns insights que tive com a resposta de todos. Basicamente fiz o select que eu já tinha duas vezes, trazendo apenas os campos de "A pagar" e "A receber" se parados e depois fiz um terceiros select para poder trazer as informações formatadas e com as exceções tratadas devidamente. Vou deixar abaixo o meu código completo caso alguém tenha uma dúvida parecida.

```
;WITH [PAGA] AS (SELECT     ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA,ID_CD_PESSOA,NM_PAGREC, ISNULL(SUM(COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA,0)),0)as TOTAL_ARECEBER,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL  FROM(
    Select      
         FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
        ,FATU.ID_CD_BOOKING
        ,FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA
        ,FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
        ,FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO
        ,FATU.IN_STATUS
        ,FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_REL
        ,NM_PAGREC              = (Select
                                        CASE WHEN CRMP.IN_TIPO = 'F' THEN
                                            CRMP.NM_PESSOA+' '+CRMP.NM_SOBRENOME +'<br>'+convert(varchar,CRMP.NR_CPF_CNPJ)
                                        ELSE
                                            CRMP.NM_APELIDO  +'<br>'+convert(varchar,CRMP.NR_CPF_CNPJ)
                                        END
                                    From 
                                        TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP     CRMP
                                    Where 
                                        ID_CD_PESSOA            = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA OR ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
                                    )
        ,ID_CD_PESSOA   = (Select
                                        CASE WHEN CRMP.IN_TIPO = 'F' THEN
                                            CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA
                                        ELSE
                                            CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA
                                        END     
                                    From 
                                        TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP     CRMP
                                    Where 
                                        ID_CD_PESSOA            = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA OR ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
                                    )
        -- TIPO DE FATURA
        ,FATU.FL_CONV_MOEDA_BRL 

        -- BOOKING
        ,BOOK.DS_AMS_REFERENCE

        -- ADICIONAIS
        ,TEM_FECHAMENTO.FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO
        ,TEM_FECHAMENTO.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI

        -- FINANCEIRO
        ,TEM_LANCAMENTO.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
        ,TEM_LANCAMENTO.FL_COMPENSADO 


        ,COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL,0)        AS VL_FATURA_TOTAL
        ,COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA,0)  AS VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA
        ,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL  = (SELECT TOP(1) CASE WHEN FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA IS NOT NULL THEN FAIT.DS_MOEDA_VENDA ELSE FAIT.DS_MOEDA_CUSTO END DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL FROM TB_FATURA_ITENS_FAIT FAIT WHERE FAIT.ID_CD_FATURA = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA)
    From 
        TB_FATURA_FATU              FATU INNER JOIN
        TB_BOOKING_BOOK             BOOK ON BOOK.ID_CD_BOOKING      = FATU.ID_CD_BOOKING        INNER JOIN
        TB_FATURAS_TIPOS_FATP       FATP ON FATP.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO  = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO    INNER JOIN
        TB_LOGIN_LOGI               LOGI ON LOGI.ID_CD_LOGIN        = FATU.ID_CD_LOGIN
        OUTER APPLY (
            Select top 1 
                FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO = 'S'
                ,FAPR2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI 
            From 
                TB_FATURA_AUX_FPAX FPAX2 INNER JOIN 
                TB_FATURA_PRINCIPAL_FAPR FAPR2 ON FAPR2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI = FPAX2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI  
            Where 
                FPAX2.ID_CD_FATURA = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA AND FAPR2.IN_STATUS = 1
        ) AS TEM_FECHAMENTO

        OUTER APPLY (    
                        SELECT TOP 1 
                            ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  
                            ,FL_COMPENSADO = ( SELECT TOP 1 
                                                    'N'
                                                FROM 
                                                    TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP2 
                                                WHERE 
                                                    FNLP2.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  = FNLP.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
                                                AND FNLP2.ID_CD_AUXILIAR    = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                                                AND FNLP2.FL_AUXILIAR       = 'FAT'  
                                                AND FNLP2.FL_SITUACAO       = 'A')
                            ,DT_ULTIMO_PAGTO = ( SELECT TOP 1 
                                                    FNLP3.DT_COMPENSADO
                                                FROM 
                                                    TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP3 
                                                WHERE 
                                                    FNLP3.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  = FNLP.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
                                                AND FNLP3.ID_CD_AUXILIAR    = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                                                AND FNLP3.FL_AUXILIAR       = 'FAT'  
                                                AND (FNLP3.FL_SITUACAO      = 'C' OR FNLP3.FL_SITUACAO      = 'G')
                                                ORDER BY ID_CD_PARCELA DESC)
                        FROM 
                            TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP 
                        WHERE 
                            FNLP.ID_CD_AUXILIAR = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                        AND FNLP.FL_AUXILIAR    = 'FAT'  
                        AND FNLP.FL_CANCELADO   = 'N'
                    ) AS TEM_LANCAMENTO
                        WHERE ID_CD_FATURA <> '' ) TB       
                        WHERE ((ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO = '3' AND IN_STATUS = '1' ) AND (ID_CD_FATURA_PRI IS NULL AND ID_CD_LANCAMENTO IS NULL )) AND ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA <> ''
                        GROUP BY
                        ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA,ID_CD_PESSOA,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL,NM_PAGREC,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL )

[RECEBE] AS (SELECT ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE,ID_CD_PESSOA,NM_PAGREC, isnull(SUM(COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA,0)),0)as TOTAL_APAGAR,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL  FROM(
                Select      
                     FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                    ,FATU.ID_CD_BOOKING
                    ,FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA
                    ,FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
                    ,FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO
                    ,FATU.IN_STATUS
                    ,FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_REL
                    ,NM_PAGREC              = (Select
                                                    CASE WHEN CRMP.IN_TIPO = 'F' THEN
                                                        CRMP.NM_PESSOA+' '+CRMP.NM_SOBRENOME +'<br>'+convert(varchar,CRMP.NR_CPF_CNPJ)
                                                    ELSE
                                                        CRMP.NM_APELIDO  +'<br>'+convert(varchar,CRMP.NR_CPF_CNPJ)
                                                    END
                                                From 
                                                    TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP     CRMP
                                                Where 
                                                    ID_CD_PESSOA            = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA OR ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
                                                )
                    ,ID_CD_PESSOA   = (Select
                                                    CASE WHEN CRMP.IN_TIPO = 'F' THEN
                                                        CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA
                                                    ELSE
                                                        CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA
                                                    END
                                                From 
                                                    TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP     CRMP
                                                Where 
                                                    ID_CD_PESSOA            = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA OR ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
                                                )
                    -- TIPO DE FATURA
                    ,FATU.FL_CONV_MOEDA_BRL 

                    -- BOOKING
                    ,BOOK.DS_AMS_REFERENCE

                    -- ADICIONAIS
                    ,TEM_FECHAMENTO.FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO
                    ,TEM_FECHAMENTO.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI

                    -- FINANCEIRO
                    ,TEM_LANCAMENTO.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
                    ,TEM_LANCAMENTO.FL_COMPENSADO 


                    ,COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL,0)        AS VL_FATURA_TOTAL
                    ,COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA,0)  AS VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA
                    ,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL  = (SELECT TOP(1) CASE WHEN FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA IS NOT NULL THEN FAIT.DS_MOEDA_VENDA ELSE FAIT.DS_MOEDA_CUSTO END DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL FROM TB_FATURA_ITENS_FAIT FAIT WHERE FAIT.ID_CD_FATURA = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA)
                From 
                    TB_FATURA_FATU              FATU INNER JOIN
                    TB_BOOKING_BOOK             BOOK ON BOOK.ID_CD_BOOKING      = FATU.ID_CD_BOOKING        INNER JOIN
                    TB_FATURAS_TIPOS_FATP       FATP ON FATP.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO  = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO    INNER JOIN
                    TB_LOGIN_LOGI               LOGI ON LOGI.ID_CD_LOGIN        = FATU.ID_CD_LOGIN
                    OUTER APPLY (
                        Select top 1 
                            FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO = 'S'
                            ,FAPR2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI 
                        From 
                            TB_FATURA_AUX_FPAX FPAX2 INNER JOIN 
                            TB_FATURA_PRINCIPAL_FAPR FAPR2 ON FAPR2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI = FPAX2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI  
                        Where 
                            FPAX2.ID_CD_FATURA = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA AND FAPR2.IN_STATUS = 1
                    ) AS TEM_FECHAMENTO

                    OUTER APPLY (    
                                    SELECT TOP 1 
                                        ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  
                                        ,FL_COMPENSADO = ( SELECT TOP 1 
                                                                'N'
                                                            FROM 
                                                                TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP2 
                                                            WHERE 
                                                                FNLP2.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  = FNLP.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
                                                            AND FNLP2.ID_CD_AUXILIAR    = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                                                            AND FNLP2.FL_AUXILIAR       = 'FAT'  
                                                            AND FNLP2.FL_SITUACAO       = 'A')
                                        ,DT_ULTIMO_PAGTO = ( SELECT TOP 1 
                                                                FNLP3.DT_COMPENSADO
                                                            FROM 
                                                                TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP3 
                                                            WHERE 
                                                                FNLP3.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO  = FNLP.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
                                                            AND FNLP3.ID_CD_AUXILIAR    = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                                                            AND FNLP3.FL_AUXILIAR       = 'FAT'  
                                                            AND (FNLP3.FL_SITUACAO      = 'C' OR FNLP3.FL_SITUACAO      = 'G')
                                                            ORDER BY ID_CD_PARCELA DESC)
                                    FROM 
                                        TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP 
                                    WHERE 
                                        FNLP.ID_CD_AUXILIAR = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
                                    AND FNLP.FL_AUXILIAR    = 'FAT'  
                                    AND FNLP.FL_CANCELADO   = 'N'
                                ) AS TEM_LANCAMENTO
                                    WHERE ID_CD_FATURA <> '' ) TB       
                                    WHERE ((ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO = '3' AND IN_STATUS = '1' ) AND (ID_CD_FATURA_PRI IS NULL AND ID_CD_LANCAMENTO IS NULL )) AND ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE <> ''
                                    GROUP BY
                                    ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE,ID_CD_PESSOA,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL,NM_PAGREC,DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL)

SELECT Z.ID_CD_PESSOA as ID_AGENTE, 
   Z.NM_PESSOA AS AGENTE,     
   R.[TOTAL_APAGAR] AS A_PAGAR,
   R.[DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL] AS MOEDA,
   P.[TOTAL_ARECEBER] AS A_RECEBER,
   P.[DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL] AS MOEDA,

   ISNULL(P.[TOTAL_ARECEBER],0) - ISNULL(R.[TOTAL_APAGAR],0) AS [TOTAL_SALDO],
   MOEDA_SALDO =         (Case WHEN
                            P.[DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL] IS NULL 
                          THEN R.[DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL]
                          ELSE P.DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL
                          END)
FROM [TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP] AS Z 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [PAGA] AS P ON Z.ID_CD_PESSOA = P.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  [RECEBE] AS R ON Z.ID_CD_PESSOA = R.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE
WHERE ((P.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA IS NOT NULL AND R.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE IS NULL) 
      OR (P.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA IS NULL AND R.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE IS NOT NULL) 
      OR (P.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA IS NOT NULL AND R.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE IS NOT NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

a lógica do das faturas e do saldo colocaria desta forma. Quando quero N linhas agrupadas no resultado (numa só row e column).

```
, 'FATURA' = ISNULL(
                (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + F.[ID] 
                    FROM [dbo].[fatura_lines] F WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE F.ID = CC.ID
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'') AS FATURA)
            , '')
```

Comment: Me desculpe Ernesto porém não compreendi a sua resposta. Peço desculpas pela burrice.

Comment: Olá viva, com a function STUFF consegues consultar n faturas e retorna numa só linha como no teu exemplo "15997, 16428", ou seja com varias linhas de resultado apresentas numa só linha,  é na verdade o que procuras, com esta abordagem simplificas a tua query. Este exemplo é só para uma linha, neste caso "FATURA".

Comment: Ahh sim, compreendi, não tinha conhecimento deste STUFF como uma function. Obrigado pelo ensinamento.